# Expectation value of a state eigenvalue

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue, observables

Why is it such that Expectation value of an Observable quantity is always equal to one of the eigenvalue of the its operator? an it be proved mathematically?

Comment: The expectation value is *not* equal to one of the eigenvalues. E.g., if you have an operator that has eigenvalues 1 and -1 on a 2D Hilbert space, you can have *any* expectation value between -1 and 1 on states. I don'T know what you are asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise of the question is false.  [Is the expectation value always an eigenvalue?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37781/9887)